# Thread doesn't stop even when condition is no longer met in the loop

Tags: java, multithreading

As the title, I create a thread and start it from the method newOpponent below.

That thread has a while condition `while(OpponentsMap.get(type)!=null&&isPlayerAlive&&game.getFuel()>0.0)` 
and I know that thread `OpponentsMap.get(type)` was changed to null so now the condition shouldn't be meet it still goes loops forever. What am I missing?

```
public Thread newOpponent(Type type){
    boolean valueSet = true;
    Poi opponent = randomLocationOpponent(type);
    OpponentsMap.replace(type, opponent);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //Inform EDT about GUI changes
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(OpponentsMap.get(type)!=null){
                    radar.addPoi(OpponentsMap.get(type));
                }
            }
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            double[] XYSpeed = getXYSpeedTowardsPlayer(type);

            while(OpponentsMap.get(type)!=null&&isPlayerAlive&&game.getFuel()>0.0){
                moveOpponent(type, XYSpeed[0], XYSpeed[1]);
                System.out.println(OpponentsMap.get(type).getName()+" distance: "+distanceToPlayer(OpponentsMap.get(type)));

                if(distanceToPlayer(OpponentsMap.get(type))>2) {
                    System.out.println("destroy");
                    destroyOpponent(type);
                }
                System.out.println("Is null: "+(OpponentsMap.get(type)==null)+" IsPlayerAlive: "+isPlayerAlive+" isFuelAbove0: "+(game.getFuel()>0.0) );
                try {
                    sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GameOpponents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return thread;
}

private void destroyOpponent(Type type){
    OpponentsMap.replace(type,null);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(OpponentsMap.get(type)!=null){
                radar.removePoi(OpponentsMap.get(type));

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Update;**
I have tried making the hashmap volatile and also changed it to concurrenthashmap but it still doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: Try making `OpponentsMap` volatile.

Comment: @shmosel I did unfortunately the loop keeps going, OpponentsMap is a hashmap.

Comment: First of all While loop will definitely break if OpponentsMap.get(type)==null. There are couple of factors that matters here  1) Type immutable? (if not somewhere along the line value is changing and hash will return different bucket where value is not null may be)  2) May be your code is stuck at 'double[] XYSpeed = getXYSpeedTowardsPlayer(type)' and not proceeding. That's all i can think of now, However this is incomplete information to come to any conclusion.